# Windows 10 Service "Log On As" User Gives Error "Access Denied"

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, permissions, services

I am trying to start a service automatically but log on with a specific credential.

Here is an example:

[image: Windows 10 Service Properties]

The specific service does NOT matter, as the problem happens with any service, namely that I get `Access Denied`.

I am aware that the user must have rights to log on as a service. That requires going to the `Local Security Policy` editor, `secpol.msc` and then the path as shown in this screenshot. I did add the specific user to the list. The system got restarted afterwards, just because, and I still get `Access Denied`.

[image: Local Security Policy showing Log on a a service]

I did try downloading `[Process Monitor][3]` from systernals and searching for `Access Denied` but maybe for an expert in that tool would have been helpful, but for me that turned up a dead end.

I was thinking some sort of permissions issue, but `Local Security Policy` should have taken care of that. The user is a domain user that has Administrative privileges on that PC.

Thoughts?

**UPDATE**

[image: Resultant Security Policy Results]

It is interesting that on the left, I see the user, but on the right, not defined, then again I never heard of rsop before.

**GPUpdate /Force**

```
Computer policy could not be updated successfully. The following errors were encountered:

The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of network connectivity to a domain controller. This may be a transient condition. A success message would be generated once the machine gets connected to the domain controller and Group Policy has successfully processed. If you do not see a success message for several hours, then contact your administrator.
User Policy could not be updated successfully. The following errors were encountered:
```

**HTML Report Result:**

```
The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of network connectivity to a domain controller. This may be a transient condition. A success message would be generated once the machine gets connected to the domain controller and Group Policy has successfully processed. If you do not see a success message for several hours, then contact your administrator.
```

I also received:

```
(7326) Group Policy failed to discover the Domain Controller details in 782 milliseconds.
Error Codes: 7017, 1006, 7017, 7326
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the policy is applied with gpupdate? Have you run rsop to make sure there isn’t a domain level policy overriding the local security policy? Is there any additional detail in the event logs? Are there any user restrictions in place for this user? Can you logon to the console with this user/pass?

Comment: @Appleoddity gpupdate: not yet    rsop: not yet    event logs: sadly none        restrictions: none        console: I log on all the time with those credentials     Stay tuned on the 'not yet'

Comment: @Appleoddity what command line syntax did you have in mind for gpupdate. I figure "gpupdate /Target:<something>" is what you had in mind, but do not know the something.

Comment: Just run `gpupdate /force` on the computer after you modify the local security policy.

Comment: @Appleoddity I updated the question with the results that you asked for.

Comment: This is a computer on a domain correct? You shouldn't be seeing errors about contacting a domain controller. If you can't contact a domain controller, you won't be able to login as a service with a domain user account either. You need to determine why you don't have connectivity to a domain controller. What happens if you do a `ping <your company domain>` - for example, `ping thecompany.local` - it should return an IP address of a domain controller and get a successful reply.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger Any luck with this issue?

Comment: @CodeRunner Sadly, there is no way to attach a hidden note that only I can see for a post, which would indicate the real issue along with pertinent details. It is nice to talk of XBox, but over a year later, I do not recall the real issue at hand or the details.

Comment: You can try configuring the service credentials through command line and than check event viewer for errors, maybe it will give a better clue for the root cause (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1324787/2546759)